# Hide function hidden contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contact-form

Contact form sending, no problem.javascript code; sucess function in hide() not working.I want to hide html div id="contactform"

What is the problem? Contact form html in div hide why not working?

**HTML CODE**

```
 <!--sending after div hide not working?-->  
 <div id="contactform"> 
                          <form id="contact" action="">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label for="name" id="name_label">NAME</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="50" value="" class="text-input" >
                                <span class="error" id="name_error">PLEASE NAME</span>
                                <label for="email" id="email_label">EMAIL</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="50" value="" class="text-input" >
                                <span class="error" id="email_error">PLEASE EMAIL</span>
                                <span class="error" id="email_error2">EMAIL ERROR</span>
                                <label for="phone" id="phone_label">TELEPHONE</label>
                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"  value="" class="text-input" >
                                <label for="msg" id="msg_label">MESSAGE TEXT</label>
                                <textarea cols="60" rows="5" name="msg" id="msg" class="text-input"></textarea>
                                <span class="error" id="msg_error">PLEASE MESSAGE</span><br >
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Gonder" >
                            </fieldset>
                          </form>
                          <div id="message"></div>
                        </div>
```

**JavaScript CODE**

```
          jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "aspmail.asp",
          data: dataString,
          success: function() {
          jQuery('#contactform').html("<div id='message'></div>");
            jQuery('#message').html("<strong>Message send</strong>")
      .append("<p>thank you</p>")
      .hide() // not working hide?
               .fadeIn(1500, function() {
              jQuery('');
            });
          }
         });
        return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: What actually does happen? What I would expect to happen with that JS code is for all of your labels and input fields to disappear and then the text "Message send thank you" to fade in. (And in fact that _is_ what happens when I paste the body of your success handler into a test like this: http://jsfiddle.net/64Bj8/) Note that the reason the labels and inputs disappear _isn't_ because of `.hide()`, it's because you overwrite the contents of the `#contactform` div with `jQuery('#contactform').html("<div id='message'></div>");`.

Comment: Send form after, div id="contactform" hide not working?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console? And are you sure the success handler is even being called? Try adding `alert("In success");` as the _first_ line of the success function and see what happens.

Comment: ashley, localhost working codes but hosting in contact form div hide not working.

Comment: Just tested, works as expected. Have you checked console for errors? Is it just the hide not working (the div is being updated?)

Comment: link:http://www.sarigultadilat.com/sample/index.html

Comment: contact page in contact form send after form div hide not working?

Comment: At the page you linked to the form _is_ hiding. Your "message sent / thank you" text is not fading in though - is that what you're asking about?

Comment: no, div hide not working?

Comment: I filled in your contact form and pressed the submit button and the form disappeared.

Comment: :) very strange. Did not work 5 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try .css("display", "none") instead of hide()

Comment: I do not understand, how?

Comment: Send form after, div id="contactform" hide not working.